# How can I insert a document from a bash script to mongodb?

Tags: bash, mongodb, insert

What is the exact code I need to execute, to insert a document into a mongodb using bash. At the moment I am able to look documents in mongodb via bash script up, but inserting does not work.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can inject javascript code from a javascript file:

```
mongo  127.0.0.1/MyDatabase script.js
```

with script.js:

```
var document = {
    name  : "document_name",
    title : "document_title"
};

db.MyCollection.insert(document);
```

or directly:

```
mongo 127.0.0.1/MyDatabase --eval 'var document = { name : "document_name", title : "document_title" }; db.MyCollection.insert(document);'
```

Comment: just FYI to anyone finding this: if you try to use `console.log()` in `script.js` you'll get an error that it's not defined. the equivalent is `print()` for mongo scripts. and `printjson()` is helpful too

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to serve script from a file (I try not to source external files as much as possible) or not use `--eval` option which can be difficult to read if you have many entries, you can use a `bash` [heredoc](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html)

You can type in terminal:

```
-bash-4.1$ mongo mongodb://myServerAddress/myDbName <<EOF
> db.myCollectionName.insert({
> name: "doc name",
> title: "doc title"
> })
> EOF
```

Result:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.1
connecting to: mongodb://myServerAddress/myDbName
MongoDB server version: 3.0.7
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
bye
-bash-4.1$
```

If you want to keep it in a script, just remove `>` which is actually prompt for a multiline command.

For in-script use, it should be as below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mongo mongodb://myServerAddress/myDbName <<EOF
db.myCollectionName.insert({
    name: "doc name",
    title: "doc title"
})
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

#### insert some JSON into Mongo DB `sample_db`, collection `products_coll`

```
echo '{ item: "card", qty: 115 }' | \
 sed 's@^@db.products_coll.insert( @; s@$@ ) @'   | mongo sample_db

MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/sample_db
MongoDB server version: 3.6.3
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })
bye
```

#### make sure it is here

```
mongoexport -d sample_db -c products_coll

{"_id":{"$oid":"5d27e83152a049227799710e"},"item":"card","qty":115.0}
```

Comment: In my opinion, this answer is closer to the best solution. It uses stdin and pipe which makes it usable in a kind of a functional way.